# how to pass value in input hidden using jquery and laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5, dynamic-forms

i have dynamic form value in jquery and how to pass value in input hidden to store in database?

[image]

[image]

Comment: include all relevant code in OP not an image

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller you could get any input sent by its name.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $totalPrice = $request->input('total_price');

    }
}
```